# How to understand linearizability a distributed system?

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system

All literatures I know regarding linearizability explain it as something related with real time like this:

1. The execution history can be reordered to be equivalent to some legal sequential history `s`.
2. The history `s` must be consistent with the real time order.

The concept of linearizability is originally defined in this [paper](https://cs.brown.edu/~mph/HerlihyW90/p463-herlihy.pdf), which considers the correctness of concurrent objects accessed in a multi-processor environment. So the real time can be understood as the wall clock of the computer.

But in a distributed system the clock is not synchronized, how to understand the real time order?

Comment: I wish I understand it well enough to give you an answer but I found http://www.bailis.org/blog/linearizability-versus-serializability/ to be helpful

Comment: @dm03514 I read this article before, but his explanation also involves wall clock time.

Comment: Not really a satisfying answer but I think that in theory, linearizability assumes some sort of global clock, even if this may not be feasible in reality. How linearizability is actually achieved in practice is a different story.